# SSH X11 Tunneling no longer working with ipv6 disabled

Tags: server, 20.04, ssh, xorg

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 server where ssh X tunnelling has always worked, so that my colleagues can run programs like qgis et co using MobaXTerm on windows or just `SSH -XC` (the few) on Linux.

The problem now it is no longer working with xclock telling me it can't open the display (and indeed I have nothing on `echo $DISPLAY`)

If I understood correctly the (old) documentation on [ServerGUI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI), there are two ways to get graphical applications forwarded on SSH:

1. Use `xauth` on the host (server) and the actual X server on the client
2. Use a full yet minimal `xorg` + `openbox` on the server
   I have tried both approaches but can't get it working. Also I do not understand the advantages of using one or the other (my machine has 128GB of RAM)

I already have set `ForwardX11 yes` and `ForwardX11Trusted yes` on `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `X11Forwarding yes` on `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (and played with both `yes` and `no` on
`X11UseLocalhost`)

So, what am I missing to get back SSH X tunneling working ? Can be a problem of iptable firewall (but "normal" SSH works - albeit on a non standard 55000 port) ?

EDIT:
That seems to be related to having disabled IPV6 on `/etc/sysctl.con`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=1
```

I do not want however ipv6, somehow my IPS reports very large amount of data with ipv6 on and I haven't put any iptables rules on ipv6....
Is there a way to tell sshd to use ipv4 for tunnelling? I have tried adding `AddressFamily inet` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved as described [here](https://www.makethenmakeinstall.com/2012/06/x-forwarding-with-ipv6-disabled-on-ubuntu) and [here](https://gist.github.com/adrianratnapala/1324845/b0d3df437ee5df5beef4bc1aed89af8c98a4246d), by adding
`AddressFamily inet` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` AND removing `~/.Xauthority`.

In this way I can get X11 ssh tunneling and ipv6 disabled.